# Add/Remove Highstock stock tools?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to remove some of the stock tools provided by highstock (for eg: removing full screen option or removing save chart options etc.) for its stock chart with gui. I am not able to find a good way to do that, rather than removing the link to the library for that tool (i.e, removing techincal indicator itself).

Can someone help me out in this?
Thanks

Comment: You will find all you need in the [API documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set GUI options in `stockTools.gui` object.

**Code:**

```
  stockTools: {
    gui: {
        buttons: ['simpleShapes', 'lines', 'saveChart' ]
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p42knLvg/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/stockTools.gui.buttons

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer was helpful for you please upvote or mark it as a correct one, thanks.